# OpenPYXL - Open / save changes formatting

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel file containing some time sheets, and for some reason when saving it, the formatting gets lost.

The code is really easy:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
inoutXL = load_workbook(sys.argv[3])
inoutXL.save(sys.argv[3] + ".xlsx")
```

The resulting Excel file is 274kb in size, the original is 351kb. Why is this happening? The whole formatting has changed completely.

Note: I had originally some code that would alter values in the sheets, but I boiled it down to opening / saving the file already causing the issues.

Comment: `openpyxl` isn't Excel, so the file won't be byte-for-byte identical, no matter what. As to the formatting, is there maybe some formatting in the original that `openpyxl` doesn't support? The only way to get behaviour that is exactly what Excel does is to use a module that communicates with Excel via COM (`win32com` or `xlwings`) and gets Excel to do the actual work.

Comment: @BoarGules I think you should write it down as a real answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openpyxl` isn't Excel, so the file won't be byte-for-byte identical, no matter what. As to the formatting, is there maybe some formatting in the original that `openpyxl` doesn't support? Looking at similar questions on SO over the past 2 years or so, and related issues on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues), it seems that emulating Excel formatting exactly is *very* hard to do. You might want to raise this issue there.

The only way to get behaviour that is exactly what Excel does is to use a module that communicates with Excel via COM (`win32com` or `xlwings`) and gets Excel to do the actual work.

(Proposed as an answer on the advice of Walter Tross)